# SQL query to return a columns with given range

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table `tblItems` with records having the same `UniqueID` and `Description` but with different `dates` and `amount`.

Now I want to show the records by grouping them together using the `UniqueIDs` and then display the `Amount` under a dynamically created `Date` column using the same record.

Date range will be provided as parameter like `start date` and `end date` and based on the date range there might be N number of columns.

Described with the example....

#### tblItems table

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ UNIQUECODE ║    DESCRIPTION     ║   DATE   ║ AMOUNT  ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ ABCD       ║ Item Decsription 1 ║ 1/3/2014 ║ 2068    ║
║ PQRS       ║ Item Decsription 2 ║ 1/5/2014 ║ 412.104 ║
║ PQRS       ║ Item Decsription 2 ║ 1/5/2014 ║ 635.448 ║
║ UVWX       ║ Item Decsription 3 ║ 1/5/2014 ║ 214.52  ║
║ UVWX       ║ Item Decsription 3 ║ 1/7/2014 ║ 827.2   ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

I want to display this result as:

```
╔════════════╦════════════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ UNIQUECODE ║    DESCRIPTION     ║ 1/3/2014 ║ 1/5/2014 ║ 1/7/2014 ║  Total   ║
╠════════════╬════════════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ ABCD       ║ Item Decsription 1 ║     2068 ║ 0        ║ 0        ║ 2068     ║
║ PQRS       ║ Item Decsription 2 ║        0 ║ 1047.552 ║ 0        ║ 1047.552 ║
║ UVWX       ║ Item Decsription 3 ║        0 ║ 214.52   ║ 827.2    ║ 1041.72  ║
╚════════════╩════════════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Duplicate question :-http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86993/how-to-get-the-sum-of-a-particular-item-id-in-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use dynamic SQL to pivot your data. Here try this out.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblItems') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tblItems;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tblItemsTotal') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##tblItemsTotal;

CREATE TABLE #tblItems
(
    UniqueCode CHAR(4),
    [Description] VARCHAR(100),
    [Date] Date,
    Amount Decimal(18,3)
);

INSERT INTO #tblItems
VALUES  ('ABCD','Item Description 1','01/03/2014',2068),
        ('PQRS','Item Description 2','01/05/2014',412.104),
        ('PQRS','Item Description 2','01/07/2014',635.448),
        ('UVWX','Item Description 3','01/05/2014',214.52),
        ('UVWX','Item Description 3','01/07/2014',827.2);

--Now that I've set up the problem, here's for the actual code

--Declare your date range and variables to hold column lists
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '01/03/2014',
        @endDate DATE = '01/07/2014',
        @SelectCols VARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotCols VARCHAR(MAX);

--Caluclate column lists
SELECT  @SelectCols =  COALESCE(@SelectCols + ',','') + 'ISNULL(pvt.' + QUOTENAME(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(25))) + ',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(25))),
        @PivotCols =  COALESCE(@PivotCols + ',','') + QUOTENAME(CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(10)))
FROM    #tblItems
WHERE   [Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY [Date];

--Calculate your total within data range
SELECT  UniqueCode,
        [Description],
        SUM(amount) Total INTO ##tblItemsTotal
FROM #tblItems
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY UniqueCode,[Description];

--Use dynamic SQL to pivot your data and join to ##tblItemsTotal for the Total column
EXEC
(
    'SELECT pvt.UniqueCode,
            pvt.[Description],' +
            @selectCols +
            ',B.Total
     FROM #tblItems A
     PIVOT
     (
        SUM(Amount) FOR [Date] IN (' + @PivotCols + ')
     ) pvt
     INNER JOIN ##tblItemsTotal B 
     ON pvt.UniqueCode = B.UniqueCode'
)
```