# SUM of column by GROUP BY which is WHithin a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

i want to display the rows GROUP BY main Reference Id and then show the amount GROUP BY type.

[image: Table Structure]

this my query

```
SELECT gl.`drcr`,gl.`amount`,gl.`name`,gl.`type`,
       gl.`narration`,gl.`main_reference`,gl.`date` "        
. "FROM `general_ledger` AS gl "
. "INNER JOIN ( "
. " SELECT SUM(amount) AS total 
    FROM `general_ledger` GROUP BY `type` ) AS tot "
. "WHERE gl.`date` BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' "
. "GROUP BY gl.`main_reference`,gl.`date`,gl.`name`,
            gl.`type`,gl.`amount`,gl.`drcr`,gl.`narration`
```

if main reference id and type same want to add both row amount and need to display as one row like
[image: display image]
please help me.. 
thanks in advance

Comment: ,https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86993/how-to-get-the-sum-of-a-particular-item-id-in-a-column

Comment: thanks haidar, in this answer they SUM the column by using One GROUP BY , but in my case need to do two group by function operation.. like first have to show all the rows GROUP BY main reference and then Merge the same mainreference and type rows and show the total of both in one rows instead of showing duplicate

Comment: Can you provide DDL and DML for this problem -  in an SQLFiddle or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `drcr`,SUM(`amount`) 
`amount`,`name`,`type`,`narration`,`main_reference`,`date`
FROM (
    SELECT gl.`drcr`,gl.`amount`,gl.`name`,gl.`type`,gl.`narration`,gl.`main_reference`,gl
  .`date` "
                              . "FROM `general_ledger` AS gl "
                              . "INNER JOIN ( "
                              . " SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM `general_ledger` GROUP BY `type` ) AS tot "
                              . "WHERE gl.`date` BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' "
                              . "GROUP BY gl.`main_reference`,gl.`date`,gl.`name`,gl.`type`,gl.`amount`,gl.`drcr`,gl.`narration` 
) Interimresults
GROUP BY `drcr`, `name`,`type`,`narration`,`main_reference`,`date`
```

Comment: Thanks Alocyte Its Worked.  In The Last Group By i changed the order , like start from main_reference